# Which kernel versions does the udev exploit work?

Tags: rooting, kernel

Which kernel versions does [the udev exploit](http://thesnkchrmr.wordpress.com/2011/03/27/udev-exploit-exploid/) work? Upon googling this, I found articles claiming that it works on Android 2.1 and maybe 2.2, but there is no information about the kernel versions.

Comment: We can't help you find the kernel, as it would be considered a shopping recommendation -- [this](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/17152/1465) may be helpful with that however.

Comment: I am just trying to do some research, for which I need the kernel **version**. I don't want to buy a device. I am not going to *shop* for anything.

Comment: Whether you pay money is irrelevant -- searching for something to acquire (the kernel) is shopping by SE's standards.  We can help you figure out when the exploit was patched / the versions where it is unpatched, but actually finding somewhere to get the kernel is off-topic.  See the [FAQ].

Comment: Fine, can you tell me the  kernel version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm actually not sure that the kernel version matters for this exploit. It was a bug that was patched in the platform_system_core repository, which I think comprises libraries and system files that live on in the `/system` directory (the README says as much). [The patch was committed on July 19, 2010](https://github.com/android/platform_system_core/commit/5f5d5c8cef10f28950fa108a8bd86d55f11b7ef4) (in the Froyo branch, anyway).

I'd wager that any kernel with a build date later than that also has the updated system files, so the system wouldn't be vulnerable. `uname -a` would tell you the build date of a given device's kernel, but beyond that I don't know that you could really line it up with a specific kernel version, especially on devices from different manufacturers/carriers/etc.

Comment: The patch should be helpful. Now I'll just **unpatch** that patch on the kernel that test the exploit. That should work right?

Comment: @EknathIyer: Sure, if you reversed the diff the code would be exploitable again, I would assume.